# How to make button collapse after set it to hidden in asp.net by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have 3 buttons in a row on my asp.net page, I use a javascript to set the button in the middle(ButtonSR) to invisible, but by doing that, I also want the button under it to take its place instead of leaving a empty space.
Here is my asp.net code for these three button:

```
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Editing <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" id="ButtonLR" class="btn btn-inverse" style="font-weight:bold; color:white">&nbsp Load Resources</a></li>
                <li><asp:Button ID="ButtonSR" Text="Save Resources " runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-inverse" onclick="ButtonSR_Click" /></li>
                <li><a href="#" id="historyBtn" class="btn btn-inverse" style="font-weight:bold; color:white">&nbsp History</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

And here is my javascript to set the button invisible:

```
 document.getElementById('ButtonSR').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

How do I make historyBtn to take ButtonSR's place in javascript after setting ButtonSR invisible, in order to avoid empty space on my page?

Comment: then try hiding the li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
document.getElementById('ButtonSR').style.display="none";
```

Here is more info about the difference between `visibility: hidden` and `display:none`
[What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that by using jquery .hide() instead of javascript's style.visibility='hidden' the button would not leave an empty space.

So, assuming you have jquery available something like :

```
$('#ButtonSR').hide();
```